# Windows 8's Confusing Security

Tags: windows-8, security, filesystems, file-permissions

I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64. My account in the PC is an administrator account. Among several logical drives in the PC, admins have full control permission on all drives. I've confirmed this by drive's Property -> Security tab.

[image]

I use Firefox 17 as my web browser. I've set the location `E:\Downloads` for all downloads to be saved. When I initiate a download, Firefox asks me to save the file. When I click Save File button, Firefox says that it can't save the file because it doesn't have necessary permission to do so.

Similar things happen with all other software. I use 7-zip. When I try to extract contents to `E:\` drive from a zip file using 7-zip, 7-zip tells that it doesn't have permission to output files.

To summarize, my user account is admin account, admins have full control of `E:\` drive, yet I can't create contents in `E:\` through various software. Why this happens and how to resolve this issue?

I've checked that if the specific user is given full control over `E:\` drive, then all software work as expected. This I think should not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: What [NTFS permissions](http://i.imgur.com/n3Qdk.jpg) are used for E:?

Comment: @nixda: Full control. I've uploaded an image.

Comment: Under Advanced settings, what does it say who the owner is?

Comment: @Sathya: the owner of E:\ is Administrators group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you log in as an Administrator you are issued two security tokens by the operating system: one is your administrator token, the other only has standard user rights. Unless you explicitly choose to run a program as an administrator, your program only gets the standard user token. It doesn't matter that you are logged in as the administrator. You must still right click and choose the "Run as Administrator" option, or your program behaves as if you're a standard user.

This is nothing new. It's been true since Windows Vista... going on six years now.

The only ways to bypass this are to give the regular users group or a specific user account permissions on the folder, or to turn the User Account Control feature off. By far, the best option here is to give permissions to your user account or create a new group named something like "AdministratorsNoUAC", add yourself and other admins to that group, and then use that group to assign permissions to your folders.

Comment: My UAC level was set to never notify. After a google search I found that this doesn't disable UAC unlike Windows 7. A registry value needs to be set to disable UAC. But if UAC is disabled, modern UI apps won't work. So I've decided to mark Run as Administrator checkbox with the shortcuts of those programs. Thanks.

Comment: Having a browser "run as administrator" might not be the best idea though.

Comment: @Donotalo do you have a reason that running as administrator is more preferable to just giving the users group permission to the folder? letting the browser "run as administrator" is a HUGE security risk.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I'm doing that for only my account. :) Don't worry, I can take care of myself. In case I'll fail, there are super users who'll be more than happy to help me. :)